# How to prove ¬p ∧ ¬q ⊢ ¬(p ∨ q) by natural deduction?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Here's my attempt, but I think it's incorrect because I don't discharge assumption 1:

1. ¬p ∧ ¬q $\qquad$ premise
2. ¬p $\qquad$ by (∧E)
3. ¬q $\qquad$ by (∧E)
4. p $\qquad$ assumption¹
5. p ∨ q $\qquad$ assumption²
6. ⊥ $\qquad$ by (⊥I) on 2 and 4
7. ¬(p ∨ q) $\qquad$ by (→I)²

Comment: Step 4 useless. Apply Disjunction Elim to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last step as you figured is wrong "$\to$ Intro" twice gets you $p\to \neg(p\lor q)$ but that is not what you want to prove.

I suggest proving $p\to \bot$, proving $q\to \bot$, and then assuming $p\lor q$, you use "or elim" to obtain $\neg(p\lor q)$.

Comment: to clarify (→I)² means that I'm using implication introduction and discharging assumption²

Comment: When you discharged $p$ you got $p\to \neg(p\lor q)$ @Jonas Which is not what you want to prove!

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, if this fully answers your question then please accept it to remove it off the unanswered queue.

Comment: since I already have ¬p and ¬q as premises, wouldn't it be redundant to prove p → ⊥ and q → ⊥ since they are equivalent to ¬p and ¬q?

Comment: @Jonas You are correct. If you use them as short forms you don’t have to prove it.

Comment: actually, I understand now. In conjunction exclusion, if you can reach the same result each variable individually, you discharge each assumption and prove the result is true. So I reached ⊥ using each p and q. Then used p∨q → ⊥ to get ¬(p∨q). It's exactly what you said. Thanks.